# half-dictionary

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is there such a thing as a thing that returns an `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<T>` for each matching hash code in .Net 4?  That is, I want something that just uses the `GetHashCode()` and ignores the equality operator.

---

I thought I was barking up the wrong tree for a while after all these comments.  But I found these guys.  Granted it's a .net 2 implementation... but at least a few other people thought a 1:n mapping using hash keys was a good idea.  See the description for HashMap under http://recursionsw.com/Products/csharp.html

Comment: In general the only classes that get added to the BCL are the *useful* ones. I am at a loss to figure out how this could possibly be useful. Can you explain why you want this strange thing and what you're going to use it for? (That said: make a dictionary, and pass in a custom equality provider that compares hash codes, done.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks so much for the response.  Okay... I'll do that + am happy to take that approach.  Didn't know you could do custom equality comparers Dictionaries.  Nice.  Rationale: it's a special case based on small clusters of data, that group together naturally in a very large set.  It could also be done based of of a sorted list with a range of entries via a from/to.  LINQ typically enumerates through the entire list.  A hash is just so fast though.  Want it to be in memory.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: DictionaryOfLists<T> : Dictionary<T,List<T>> would do it too.  Why'd I automatically think of a way to do it with hash maps first?  Oh well.

Comment: or DictionaryOfLists<T> : Dictionary<int,List<T>> depending.  Additional overrides required.

Comment: There is a significant chance that you are misusing/abusing hash codes here.

Comment: @Jason: thanks for the warning.  I'd agree with you for many general use cases.  At the end of the day the hash algorithm is just a function mapping a domain to a range.  functions like this can be used for many things.  For example, when time allows, it'd be interesting to dig into the implementation of the .net HashSet class.

Comment: @sgtz, yeah hash algorithm is that. But `GetHashCode()` is made specifically for use in hash tables and the like. It's not meant for some grouping or anything else. You shouldn't use it for that.

Comment: @svick: I thought I was barking up the wrong tree for a while after all these comments.  But I found these guys.  Granted it's a .net 2 implementation... but at least one other person thought a 1:n mapping using hash keys was a good idea.  http://recursionsw.com/Products/csharp.html

Comment: @sgtz, it's not that using hashes in a 1:n mapping is a bad idea. But using them for anything else than efficiency gains is. Which, I think, you want to do. And I think the library you linked doesn't.

Comment: @svick: it is for efficiency.  However, it shouldn't matter what implementation I use, so long as it is a watertight encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ToLookup<>`. But I'm not sure it's what you really want. An example

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Num = (new Random()).Next(100);
}

var manyA = new List<MyClass>();

var groupedByHash = manyA.ToLookup(p => p.GetHashCode());
```

Now each group in groupedByHash will contain all the elements that share the same hashcode. You can consider them to be "equal" by your standard.

Comment: That specializes what can be done with the object beyond what I need.  It would be better to push this into the container.

Comment: @sgtz No, I'm using an extension of the container. You do the `ToLookup` ON the container.

Comment: ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx  That's functional, but can't see that'll actually use the hash to be faster.  Will it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be what you're looking for:

```
var myEnumerator = 
  from mo in myObjects where mo.GetHashCode() == SOME_HASH_TO_MATCH select mo;
```

That will give you a means to enumerate all objects (`myObjects`) that have a specific hash code.

Update:

Based on your comment, perhaps something like this?

```
Dictionary<int, List<object>> myDataStructure;

void AddItem(object item)
{
    int hashCode = item.GetHashCode();

    if (!myDataStructure.ContainsKey(hashCode)
    {
        myDataStructure.Add(new List<object>());
    }

    myDataStructure[hashCode].Add(item);
}

List<object> GetItems(int hashCode)
{
    if (!myDataStructure.Contains(hashCode))
    {
        return null; 
    }
    return myDataStructure[hashCode];
}
```

Of course you could wrap the access methods and myDataStructure in a class, or create [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for the access methods.

Comment: it's more the implementation of that query that needs to be fast.  Crudely, a dictionary puts things in buckets based on a hash code to speed things up.  I want a filtered bucket of stuff back based on some grouping implemented via a hash code.

Comment: @sgtz: Updated my response based on your comment.